# How to find the phrase count from data frame in spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How to find the word count from a column in Data frame?

I am trying to find the count of word from the column Comments from below DF

```
CustID -  Comments

101    [[Nice one, Nice One,Nice]]

102    [[This was nice, Nice]
```

Here is the code I am trying to achieve above use case

```
val result = DF1.withColumn("Count of comments ",  DF1("Comments")).map(events => (events,1)).reduce
```

Here I am not able to apply the 'reduceByKey' function on top of the tuple and only 'reduce' function is listing

Here is the expected output I am trying to achieve

```
CustID  -   Comments                      -  Count of comments**
101         [[Nice one, Nice One,Nice]]      Nice one 2, Nice 1
102         [[This was nice, Nice]           This was nice 1, Nice
```

Can anyone help me and provide the right suggestion to achieve the above output?

Comment: Can you add the schema of the dataframe?

Comment: The output is unclear to be honest.

Comment: The output is clear to me, please find the solution below

Answer (score 0):

Please find the Solution Here :

Source Data Looks like this after trimming the braces :

```
+------+----------------------+
|CustID|Comments              |
+------+----------------------+
|101   |Nice one,Nice One,Nice|
|102   |This was nice, Nice   |
+------+----------------------+
```

The code look like this :

```
  def countElments(row: Row): Row =
  {
    val str:String = row.getAs[String]("Comments")
    val list=str.split("\\,").map(_.toLowerCase()).toList
    val newCol=list.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size).mkString(",")
    Row.merge(row, Row(newCol))
  }

val rdd=df.rdd.map(row =>countElments(row))
val newSchema=df.schema.add("Count of comments", StringType, true)
val final_df=spark.createDataFrame(rdd, newSchema)
final_df.show(false)
```

The output looks like this :

```
+------+----------------------+-----------------------------+
|CustID|Comments              |Count of comments            |
+------+----------------------+-----------------------------+
|101   |Nice one,Nice One,Nice|nice -> 1,nice one -> 2      |
|102   |This was nice, Nice   |this was nice -> 1, nice -> 1|
+------+----------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks @Subhasish. By the way, iam getting following error:  java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Iam not sure where it has to be fixed

Comment: val mkString = udf(arrayCol=>arrayCol.asInstanceOf[WrappedArray[String]].toArray.mkString(","))  
val dfWithString=df.select($"arrayCol").withColumn("arrayString",mkString($"arrayCol"))

Comment: use this udf to convert your wrappedArray to String. you can specify any delimiter mkString. use the same in split on the method I have written